# Any way of repeating console.log after a switch statement?

Tags: javascript, function, file, console, switch-statement

The console.log logs the options to the user

```
console.log("Menu" + "\n" + "1. Read File" + "\n" "2. Exit")
var userInput = readlineSync.question('Option:');
```

This will log;
Menu
1. Read File
2. Quit
Option:

This is what i want repeat **EXPECT** when the user chooses 2

I convent the input to int to use switch

```
let input = parseInt(userInput)

switch (input) {
  case 0:
    text = "Off";
    break;
  case 1:
    console.log('You have selected to read csv file')
    readFile();
    break;
  case 2:
    console.log("Quitting program")
    break;
 default:
    text = "No value found";
}

function readFile(){
    var info = fs.readFileSync("FILE", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
                            if (err) throw err; 
                        console.log("display current items: \n"+data); 
                        })
                        console.log(info)
}
```

How can i get the console to log the menu and ask the user for the their input after the switch statement and function?

Comment: you can switch() on strings (or any type) in js...

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need a loop structure, like `while`.

```
function readFile(){
    ...
}
```

```
let input;

while (input != 2) {

  console.log("Menu" + "\n" + "1. Read File" + "\n" +
    "2. Exit")
  var userInput = readlineSync.question('Option:');

  input = parseInt(userInput)

  switch (input) {
    case 0:
      text = "Off";
      break;
    case 1:
      console.log('You have selected to read csv file')
      readFile();
      break;
    case 2:
      console.log("Quitting program")
      break;
    default:
      text = "No value found";
  }
}
```